# How to reach 30fps on recording audio and video using MediaCodec MediaMuxer on android?

Tags: android, camera, android-mediacodec, frame-rate, mediamuxer

I would like to record 1920x1080p, H264 video from camera and audio from mic. I started with the sample code. This only gets 15fps at the max.

https://github.com/saki4510t/AudioVideoRecordingSample

Another sample code can reach 30fps without audio.

https://github.com/google/grafika "Show + capture camera"

I am running Android 5.1, on which MediaRecorder can record AV at 30fps. But I have to access the video data before muxer.

I guess it is related to timestamp on both video and audio. I was able to reach 26fps with AV out of sync.

Any suggestions on 30fps on AudioVideoRecordingSample?

Comment: Why did you not use MediaRecorder class?

Comment: Because in one case that I only need H264 NAL raw data. If I use MediaRecorder, I get muxed stream. I have to do de-mux myself after I receive the data. It is most likely slower than MediaCodec by which I get the raw NAL data directly.

Comment: were you able to fix it? thanks